# JFrog Mission Control - Version Control with Gitlab

Tags: jfrog-mission-control

Using Mission Control, we want to use the Version Control integration with gitlb so that we have version history of all the scripts.
We are running the docker container version.

during this setup process we encountered some problems where the commits back to gitlab were failing, even though the UI said they were successful. (Long story, not really relevant but it boiled down to a restriction in the project to check whether author is a gitlab user).

The concern here is: if these commits fail AND the UI assumes they worked, there is an ability to modify and a script from MC without that change ever being reflected in version control.

How do I force MC to disallow execution of a script that has not been committed to the gitlab source control?

Mission Control V 2.1.0

Comment: As you are using Mission Control, can I assume that you have an Enterprise VP? If so, why not addressing this to JFrog Support directly?

Comment: we do have Enterprise license. but I am not the person named on the support :) It was my hope that I could get an answer here faster than trying to work through a middleman.